# Why can't I use "profile" as an app name?

Tags: django

I need a profile to extend the Django User object, so I thought to create an app to contain the profile object and related views then proceed as per the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), but I get

```
./manage.py startapp profile
CommandError: 'profile' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

I don't have an app called profile in INSTALLED_APPS and I don't know what context this message should be interpreted in. Can anybody help?

(Yes, I could call it `userprofile` or `xxx_profile` instead, but I'd like to understand why I need to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It conflicts with an already excisting library, not made by you

Any other name that isnt a library should be fine

Answer (score 4):

It conflicts with std lib module profile:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Answer (score 0):

think with me if you have app called `math` when python tries to import it what it will import your `app` or the `math` module in python **the modules must have unique names**

You Can name it `profile_app`